# By using TreeList how can we retrieve data from database and show it on delphi form

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How to retrieve data from database and display in Ttreeview in delphi form here is what I tried but not working  can any 1 suggest me any modifications.. Thank u...

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  // node : TTreeList;
  i: Integer;
  MyTreeNode1,MyTreeNode2 : TTreeNode;
begin
   with TreeList1.Items do
   begin
        Clear;
        MyTreeNode1 := Add(nil, 'Table');
        ADOTable1.First;
        while ADOTable1 do
        begin
            AddChild(MyTreeNode1,'B') ;
            AddChild(MyTreeNode1,'c');
            Next;
        end;
   end;
end;
```

In place of b and c data has to bind from database that is my requirement... help me..

Comment: pls provide you table data and corresponding tree structure you want to achieve

Comment: I think you meant to say `while not ADOTable1.Eof do`

Comment: ADOTable1 is a dataset that I have used...

Comment: Change the while loop as I suggest above and try again. As it is the while loop will never run because ADOTable1.Eof will be false if you have any rows returned.